# Errors of indirect measurments

Tags: error-analysis

Having some troubles with calculating the errors of indirect measurements. Any help is appreciated!

I calculated the mass absorption coefficients for different materials and now I need to evaluate the energy of gamma photons using table values (first column - magnitudes of energies, second, third and fourth - mass absorption coefficients for different materials):
[image]

How can I evaluate the magnitude of errors of energies if I know the errors of mass absorption coefficients?

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Assuming that your calculations of the absorption coefficients are accurate, the errors in the energies are related to the measurement errors of the mass absorption coefficients. Get a good book on propagation of errors.